# Optimistic Locking doesn't work - no version increment, no exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I'am using org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository to save my entities.

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="ThirdClass")
public abstract class ThirdClassBase
    extends BaseDomainObject
    implements Serializable, Cloneable{

    /**
    * Default serialID to prevent warning
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*
    * A T T R I B U T E S
    */
    @Id
    private String pk;
    @Version
    private Integer version;

    ...
}
```

Here my spring-config:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- only components from this package can be wired by spring --> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.envmuster.*" />

    <!-- Directory to scan for repository classes -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="test.domain.repository" />

    <!-- jdbc.properties => used to put db-connection data to an own property-file -->
    <bean id="domainPropertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>test.domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

The test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-test-config.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
@Transactional
public class OptimisticLockingTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private ThirdClassRepository thirdRepository;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpData(){
        ThirdClass thirdClass = new ThirdClass(3L);
        thirdClass.setPk("pk1");
        thirdClass.setVersion(30);
        thirdClass = thirdRepository.save(thirdClass);
        Assert.assertEquals(thirdClass.getVersion(), new Integer(30));
    }

    @Test
    public void optimisticLockingCheck(){
        ThirdClass thirdClass = thirdRepository.findByPK("pk1");
        Assert.assertEquals(thirdClass.getVersion(), new Integer(30));
        thirdClass.setValue(5L);

        thirdClass.setVersion(5);

        thirdClass = thirdRepository.save(thirdClass);

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void deleteData(){
        thirdRepository.delete("pk1");
    }

}
```

The test-result in the console:

```
Hibernate: select thirdclass0_.pk as pk2_8_3_, thirdclass0_.secondClass_pk as secondCl5_8_3_, thirdclass0_.value as value3_8_3_, thirdclass0_.version as version4_8_3_, secondclas1_.pk as pk2_2_0_, secondclas1_.id as id3_2_0_, secondclas1_.thirdClass_pk as thirdCla5_2_0_, secondclas1_.version as version4_2_0_, secondclas1_.wayone_pk as wayone_p6_2_0_, fourthclas2_.SecondClass_pk as SecondCl1_2_5_, fourthclas3_.pk as fourthCl2_3_5_, fourthclas3_.pk as pk2_0_1_, fourthclas3_.prop as prop3_0_1_, fourthclas3_.secondClass_pk as secondCl5_0_1_, fourthclas3_.version as version4_0_1_, thirdclass4_.pk as pk2_8_2_, thirdclass4_.secondClass_pk as secondCl5_8_2_, thirdclass4_.value as value3_8_2_, thirdclass4_.version as version4_8_2_ from ThirdClass thirdclass0_ left outer join SecondClass secondclas1_ on thirdclass0_.secondClass_pk=secondclas1_.pk left outer join SecondClass_FourthClass fourthclas2_ on secondclas1_.pk=fourthclas2_.SecondClass_pk left outer join FourthClass fourthclas3_ on fourthclas2_.fourthClass_pk=fourthclas3_.pk left outer join ThirdClass thirdclass4_ on secondclas1_.thirdClass_pk=thirdclass4_.pk where thirdclass0_.pk=? and thirdclass0_.DTYPE='ThirdClass'
Hibernate: insert into ThirdClass (secondClass_pk, value, version, DTYPE, pk) values (?, ?, ?, 'ThirdClass', ?)
Hibernate: select thirdclass0_.pk as pk2_8_3_, thirdclass0_.secondClass_pk as secondCl5_8_3_, thirdclass0_.value as value3_8_3_, thirdclass0_.version as version4_8_3_, secondclas1_.pk as pk2_2_0_, secondclas1_.id as id3_2_0_, secondclas1_.thirdClass_pk as thirdCla5_2_0_, secondclas1_.version as version4_2_0_, secondclas1_.wayone_pk as wayone_p6_2_0_, thirdclass2_.pk as pk2_8_1_, thirdclass2_.secondClass_pk as secondCl5_8_1_, thirdclass2_.value as value3_8_1_, thirdclass2_.version as version4_8_1_, myfirstcla3_.pk as pk2_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.flag as flag3_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.text as text4_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.version as version5_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.myID as myID6_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.property2 as property7_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.property3 as property8_4_2_ from ThirdClass thirdclass0_ left outer join SecondClass secondclas1_ on thirdclass0_.secondClass_pk=secondclas1_.pk left outer join ThirdClass thirdclass2_ on secondclas1_.thirdClass_pk=thirdclass2_.pk left outer join SuperClass myfirstcla3_ on secondclas1_.wayone_pk=myfirstcla3_.pk where thirdclass0_.pk=? and thirdclass0_.DTYPE='ThirdClass'
Hibernate: update ThirdClass set secondClass_pk=?, value=?, version=? where pk=? and version=?
Hibernate: select thirdclass0_.pk as pk2_8_3_, thirdclass0_.secondClass_pk as secondCl5_8_3_, thirdclass0_.value as value3_8_3_, thirdclass0_.version as version4_8_3_, secondclas1_.pk as pk2_2_0_, secondclas1_.id as id3_2_0_, secondclas1_.thirdClass_pk as thirdCla5_2_0_, secondclas1_.version as version4_2_0_, secondclas1_.wayone_pk as wayone_p6_2_0_, thirdclass2_.pk as pk2_8_1_, thirdclass2_.secondClass_pk as secondCl5_8_1_, thirdclass2_.value as value3_8_1_, thirdclass2_.version as version4_8_1_, myfirstcla3_.pk as pk2_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.flag as flag3_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.text as text4_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.version as version5_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.myID as myID6_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.property2 as property7_4_2_, myfirstcla3_.property3 as property8_4_2_ from ThirdClass thirdclass0_ left outer join SecondClass secondclas1_ on thirdclass0_.secondClass_pk=secondclas1_.pk left outer join ThirdClass thirdclass2_ on secondclas1_.thirdClass_pk=thirdclass2_.pk left outer join SuperClass myfirstcla3_ on secondclas1_.wayone_pk=myfirstcla3_.pk where thirdclass0_.pk=? and thirdclass0_.DTYPE='ThirdClass'
Hibernate: delete from ThirdClass_FourthClass where ThirdClass_pk=?
Hibernate: delete from ThirdClass where pk=? and version=?
PASSED: optimisticLockingCheck
```

I know i shouldn't set the version-property => but it isn't set automatic or at least not incremented. If i leave it null, it switches to 0 after the first save... that seems to be ok but the second save didn't increment it... so i tried to set the version manual.

Something seems to work because in the console-output i see at the update statement the "where pk =? and version=?" => but why is no exception thrown? It seems to be that the version field is used like a normal column...

Please help me, i have no idea what i did wrong. Thanks a lot in advance. BR

Dependencies (just in case):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>6.8.7</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.179</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Edit:
Another for me unexpected behavior... i use CascadeType(REMOVE, MERGE) on OneToOne-Relations. After i have added the @Version annotation it doesn't work any more. I save 2 new entities (1:1) relation by one repository.save - call but the associated relation is not saved (but no exception occured).

Comment: First off all indeed don't set the version yourself. Second which `@Version` annotation have you used JPA or the hibernate one..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i use: javax.persistence.Version

Comment: Then it should work if you have things configured correctly and on your classpath. You really have to make sure you aren't setting the version yuorself as that will confuse hibernate... Also you can only check the version AFTER the execution of the test method, as that is the point of commit not after the save method as nothing has happend then.

Comment: The whole point of persistence session is to make sure you have *only single* instance of specific entity. So testing locking within one session / transaction is not easy. You probably need to detach the entity at some point.

Comment: I removed the setting of the version by myself => now the version always stays 0. But: I think i don't get a second transaction (all test methods seems to run in the same transaction)... so may be everything is right, just my test is wrong (until i'am in the same transaction, i don't get a new version number, that would make sense). I will have a look on it and try to create a new transaction between the test-methods. Another thing: I edited my initial post (why did the Cascade-Behavior change?!). Any idea?

Comment: Also I don't really get it why you want to test this... Don't you trust the frameworks you use?

Comment: Ok, a new transaction solved the version counting issue. Testing is really complicated in that case... i need to find out how to create a new transaction easier (at the moment i just started two testclasses which access the same entity in my mem db).

Comment: @M.Deinum No, i don't trust my configuration skills ;-) And i wanted to be sure that it behaves like i understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the unexcepected behavior of the CascadeType:
Adding of @Version seems to change the saving behavior... because when i changed the CascadeType.MERGE to CascadeType.PERSIST it works again.

Something more seems to change by adding the @Version: I receive all exception only after the transaction is committed. If i remove the @Version i receive the exception at the persist method.

Comment: Just for information: This question is answered (in my opinion, i'm the questioner)), see this answer and the comments at my questions.